# Making alternative SMS sender default in Android

Tags: android, sms, android-intent

I have an app that sends SMS via Internet, and I'd like to know how to:

1)Launch my own "SmsSender" activity when user have **already** typed an sms in **default** android sms application, and presses **Send** button.I would like to get recipient number and message text.

2)or Launch my app when user tries to send sms from his adress book-I'll provide him interface for typing message.

I don't wish launching it when user selects a contact in default sms application if he won't see the conversation; I'd like to keep default messaging application working.

I've tried such code but nothing :-(

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
</intent-filter>
```

Also I'd like to know if I can integrate my app with Handset SMS.

---

P.S. Sorry for my english, I'm Russian.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should edit AndroidManifest.xml and add this `intent-filter` to the activity you want started:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="sms" />
    <data android:scheme="smsto" />
</intent-filter>
```

When the user send an SMS to a specific number, a chooser menu will be displayed. If she chooses your Application, your Activity will start.